# What keeps a delay-off timer energized when you cut off the power?

Tags: timer, electromagnetic, electricity

I've come to understand the function of the delay off timer as follows:
When it is energized, it instantly changes its contacts. And when you "de-energize" it, it delays for a preset time and only changes its contacts back to their original state after counting down.
So, my question here is how does it stay energized even when the power is cut off, and what devices are used to achieve this?

Comment: `how does it stay energized even when the power is cut off` ... are you sure that it does that?

Comment: Well it delays when its de-energized. I wanted to know what causes that

Comment: `de-energize` means `disconnect power` ..... disconnect the power to the switch and you will see that it does not stay on

Comment: If it does something at a time after the power source is removed, then there must be some stored energy in some form or another.  This could be a clockwork spring, a battery/capacitor, or whatever else the manufacturer decides to use.  Or there could be an auxiliary, always-on power connection as well.